# static member being accessed by instance reference

Tags: java

I have a call to a function and the background of that call is yellow and it says "static member being accessed by instance reference," but it works perfectly without errors.

Should I have to solve that somehow or is it okay?

Here is a code sample:

```
class A {
    static int x = 2;
    ...
}
```

Instantiation is some other file:

```
A a = new A();
a.x;
```

Comment: Is this in a particular editor or IDE that you are getting this what sounds like a warning message?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Android Studioo

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This warning happens when you have something like this:

```
class A {
 static int x = 2;
}

...

A a = new A();
a.x; // accessing static member by instance
```

You should access the static member `x` via the class (or interface) instead:

```
A a = new A();
A.x;
```

Static members belong to the class, not to a particular instance.